# Support Economics.SE beta

Tags: discussion, area51, se-sites

[A new Economics.SE is now in beta](http://economics.stackexchange.com), with the hope that it will enjoy a happier ending than the last Economics.SE beta.

I advertise it here because I believe that Math.SE users might have an interest in some of the question on the Economics.SE beta, as evidenced by [math.SE efforts to migrate some questions from the former dying beta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4049/economics-se-is-closing-can-we-salvage-some-of-the-questions).

**Disclaimer** : Math.SE has done a wonderful job at hosting mathematical economics questions so far. By no means do I suggest that this should stop or that all economics-related question on Math.SE should be migrated to Economics.SE. It is (of course) completely up to Math.SE and its user to decide which questions are amenable to the website.

Comment: If there isn't a demand for it then SE will not supply. That is why the last one failed.

Comment: @Alizter : Agreed. I hope that we will do a better job at eliciting interest and meeting SE requirements this time.